# jQuery "contains word" selector não funciona como esperado

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando utilizar o *"contains word selector"* do jQuery para **ocultar/mostrar** alguns elementos **dinamicamente** na minha página, no entanto o seletor **não está funcionando** como o esperado. Estou utilizando a versão `3.1.1` do jQuery.

Note pelo `snippet` que o código considera **apenas o ultimo valor** do atributo quando selecionado, por isto nos casos **B** e **C** há a impressão de que a seleção funcionou.. no entanto as opções **A/B** e **A/C** deveriam ficar visíveis também quando a opção **A** é selecionada novamente..

Alguem tem ideia do motivo disto? É um bug? Ou é como deve funcionar mesmo? (não é o que dá a entender a [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)).

Agradeço desde já!

```js
var options = {
  A: $('*[data-visibleOn~="A"]'),
  B: $('*[data-visibleOn~="B"]'),
  C: $('*[data-visibleOn~="C"]'),
}


$("#opt").on('change', function(evt) {
 var selected = $(this).val();
  
  for(var key in options) {
   if(options.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     if(key == selected) {
       options[key].show();
      } else {
       options[key].hide();
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>


<select name="option" id="opt">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>



<div data-visibleOn="A">A</div>
<div data-visibleOn="A B">A ou B</div>
<div data-visibleOn="B">B</div>
<div data-visibleOn="A C">A ou C</div>
<div data-visibleOn="C">C</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma forma de você implementar isso é sumindo com todos os itens antes de mostrá-los:

```
$(function() {
  var options = {
    A: $('[data-visibleOn~="A"]'),
    B: $('[data-visibleOn~="B"]'),
    C: $('[data-visibleOn~="C"]')
  };

  $("#opt").on("change", function(evt) {
      $('[data-visibleOn]').hide();    
      var selected = $(this).val();

      options[selected].show();

   }).trigger("change");
});
```

O problema é que você faz um `.hide()` nos itens que contém "A", por exemplo, porém estão nos outros conjuntos.

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/paulodiogo/pen/LXZezd?editors=1010)

Comment: Aaah que besta... é obvio, tava mostrando e depois ocultava os outros seletores. kkkk
Valeu pela resposta cara.. tava cego nisso ñ tinha me ligado.

Comment: Só tem que cuidar que o seletor `*=` é diferente do `~=`.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando o método [`$.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function) você pode passar uma função que será executada para cada elemento.

Nessa função você pode utilizar o método [`$.is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/) para testar se o elemento casa com o seletor passado para então alterar qualquer propriedade que for necessária.

No exemplo abaixo utilizei o atributo global `hidden` para isso.

```js
let $data = $("[data-visibleOn]");

$("#opt").on('change', function(evt) {
    let value = this.value;
    
    $data.prop('hidden', function() {
      return !$(this).is(`[data-visibleOn~="${value}"]`);
    });
})
```

```css
[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<select name="option" id="opt">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<div data-visibleOn="A">A</div>
<div data-visibleOn="A B">A ou B</div>
<div data-visibleOn="B">B</div>
<div data-visibleOn="A C">A ou C</div>
<div data-visibleOn="C">C</div>
```

Comment: Desculpa aí downvoter, ainda estou editando a resposta. :D